# Difference between dates between two csv files based on a unique number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files, I want the App_Date from csv_1 to be subtracted to the closest Last_Visit_Date in csv_2 based on the Mobile_Number and the Category.

**Note**: I don't want to consider the dates where App_Date == Last_Visit_Date, the Last_Visit_Date < App_Date

csv_1

```
Category     Mobile_Number      App_Date

A              503477334       2018-10-18
B              503477334       2018-10-16
C              501022162       2018-10-16
A              503487338       2018-10-13
C              506012887       2018-10-21
E              503427339       2018-10-17
```

csv_2

```
Category     Mobile_Number    Last_Visit_Date    

A              503477334        2018-10-08
B              503477334        2018-10-07
B              503477334        2018-10-09
C              501022162        2018-10-11
F              501428449        2018-10-18
C              506012887        2018-10-14
```

The output should be like below

Output

```
Category     Mobile_Number    App_Date       Last_Visit_Date   Difference

A              503477334     2018-10-18       2018-10-08       10
B              503477334     2018-10-16       2018-10-09       7
C              501022162     2018-10-16       2018-10-11       5
A              503487338     2018-10-13       2018-10-13       NaN
C              506012887     2018-10-21       2018-10-14       7 
E              503427339     2018-10-17       2018-10-17       NaN
```

**EDIT**

Finding the Difference, by excluding App_Date == Last_Visit_Day and subtracting the previous occurrence

csv_1

```
Category     Mobile_Number      App_Date

A              503477334       2018-10-18
B              503477334       2018-10-16
C              501022162       2018-10-16
A              503487338       2018-10-13
C              506012887       2018-10-21
E              503427339       2018-10-17
```

csv_2

```
Category     Mobile_Number    Last_Visit_Date    

A              503477334        2018-10-18
A              503477334        2018-10-08
A              503477334        2018-10-06
B              503477334        2018-10-07
B              503477334        2018-10-09
C              501022162        2018-10-14
A              503487338        2018-10-13
A              503487338        2018-10-11
C              506012887        2018-10-15
E              503427339        2018-10-17
```

The output should be like below

Output

```
Category     Mobile_Number    App_Date       Last_Visit_Date   Difference

A              503477334     2018-10-18       2018-10-08       10
B              503477334     2018-10-16       2018-10-09       7
C              501022162     2018-10-16       2018-10-14       2
A              503487338     2018-10-13       2018-10-11       2
C              506012887     2018-10-21       2018-10-15       6 
E              503427339     2018-10-17       2018-10-17       NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) working only with sorted columns by `datetimes`, then get difference by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and last if necessary replace missing values in `Last_Visit_Date` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
csv_1['App_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_1['App_Date'])
csv_2['Last_Visit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_2['Last_Visit_Date'])
csv_1 = csv_1.sort_values('App_Date')
csv_2 = csv_2.sort_values('Last_Visit_Date')

df = pd.merge_asof(csv_1, 
                   csv_2, 
                   left_on='App_Date', 
                   right_on='Last_Visit_Date', 
                   by=['Category','Mobile_Number'])
df['Difference'] = df['App_Date'].sub(df['Last_Visit_Date']).dt.days
df['Last_Visit_Date'] = df['Last_Visit_Date'].fillna(df['App_Date'])
print (df)
  Category  Mobile_Number   App_Date Last_Visit_Date  Difference
0        A      503487338 2018-10-13      2018-10-13         NaN
1        B      503477334 2018-10-16      2018-10-09         7.0
2        C      501022162 2018-10-16      2018-10-11         5.0
3        E      503427339 2018-10-17      2018-10-17         NaN
4        A      503477334 2018-10-18      2018-10-08        10.0
5        C      506012887 2018-10-21      2018-10-14         7.0
```

EDIT: You need parameter `allow_exact_matches` set to `False` in [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

> **allow_exact_matches** bool, default True
>   If True, allow matching with the same 'on' value (i.e. less-than-or-equal-to / greater-than-or-equal-to)
>   If False, don’t match the same 'on' value (i.e., strictly less-than / strictly greater-than).

```
csv_1['App_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_1['App_Date'])
csv_2['Last_Visit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_2['Last_Visit_Date'])
csv_1 = csv_1.sort_values('App_Date')
csv_2 = csv_2.sort_values('Last_Visit_Date')

df = pd.merge_asof(csv_1, 
                   csv_2, 
                   left_on='App_Date', 
                   right_on='Last_Visit_Date', 
                   by=['Category','Mobile_Number'],
                   allow_exact_matches=False)
print (df)
  Category  Mobile_Number   App_Date Last_Visit_Date
0        A      503487338 2018-10-13      2018-10-11
1        B      503477334 2018-10-16      2018-10-09
2        C      501022162 2018-10-16      2018-10-14
3        E      503427339 2018-10-17             NaT
4        A      503477334 2018-10-18      2018-10-08
5        C      506012887 2018-10-21      2018-10-15

df['Difference'] = df['App_Date'].sub(df['Last_Visit_Date']).dt.days
df['Last_Visit_Date'] = df['Last_Visit_Date'].fillna(df['App_Date'])
print (df)
  Category  Mobile_Number   App_Date Last_Visit_Date  Difference
0        A      503487338 2018-10-13      2018-10-11         2.0
1        B      503477334 2018-10-16      2018-10-09         7.0
2        C      501022162 2018-10-16      2018-10-14         2.0
3        E      503427339 2018-10-17      2018-10-17         NaN
4        A      503477334 2018-10-18      2018-10-08        10.0
5        C      506012887 2018-10-21      2018-10-15         6.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. What if the same date in App_Date exists in Last_Visit_Date with the same category and number, I want to exclude that and subtract only with the previous Last_Visit_Date